# CORS issue - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, spring, tomcat, spring-security, cors

I have created two web applications - client and service apps.
The interaction between client and service apps goes fine when they are deployed in same Tomcat instance.
But when the apps are deployed into seperate Tomcat instances (different machines), I get the below error when request to sent service app.

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401
```

My Client application uses JQuery, HTML5 and Bootstrap.

AJAX call is made to service as shown below:

```
var auth = "Basic " + btoa({usname} + ":" + {password});
var service_url = {serviceAppDomainName}/services;

if($("#registrationForm").valid()){
    var formData = JSON.stringify(getFormData(registrationForm));
    $.ajax({
        url: service_url+action,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        headers:{
            "Authorization":auth
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){
            //success code
        },
        error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            alert( errorThrown );
        });
}
```

My service application uses Spring MVC, Spring Data JPA and Spring Security.

I have included `CorsConfiguration` class as shown below:

`CORSConfig.java`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CORSConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("*");
    }
}
```

`SecurityConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.services", scopedProxy = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

Spring Security dependencies:

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using **Apache Tomcat** server for deployment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

CORS' preflight request uses HTTP `OPTIONS` without credentials, see [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0):

> Otherwise, make a **preflight request**. Fetch the request URL from origin source origin using referrer source as override referrer source with the manual redirect flag and the block cookies flag set, using the method OPTIONS, and with the following additional constraints:
>
> - Include an Access-Control-Request-Method header with as header field value the request method (even when that is a simple method).
> - If author request headers is not empty include an Access-Control-Request-Headers header with as header field value a comma-separated list of the header field names from author request headers in lexicographical order, each converted to ASCII lowercase (even when one or more are a simple header).
> - Exclude the author request headers.
> - Exclude user credentials.
> - Exclude the request entity body.

You have to allow anonymous access for HTTP `OPTIONS`.

**Spring Security 3**

Your modified (and simplified) code:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
       .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
           .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
           .and()
       .httpBasic()
           .and()
       .sessionManagement()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
           .and()
       .csrf().disable();
}
```

You still need your CORS configuration (probably with some additional values):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CORSConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("*");
    }
}
```

**Spring Security 4**

Since Spring Security 4.2.0 you can use the built-in support, see Spring Security Reference:

> **19. CORS**
>
> Spring Framework provides first class support for CORS. CORS must be processed before Spring Security because the pre-flight request will not contain any cookies (i.e. the `JSESSIONID`). If the request does not contain any cookies and Spring Security is first, the request will determine the user is not authenticated (since there are no cookies in the request) and reject it.
>
> The easiest way to ensure that CORS is handled first is to use the `CorsFilter`. Users can integrate the `CorsFilter` with Spring Security by providing a `CorsConfigurationSource` using the following:
>
> ```java
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>   @Override
>   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>       http
>           // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
>           .cors().and()
>           ...
>   }
>
>   @Bean
>   CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
>       CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
>       configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
>       configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
>       UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
>       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
>       return source;
>   }
> }
> ```

**Spring Security 5/6**

For Spring Security 5/6 see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title):

> **CORS**
>
> Spring Framework provides first class support for CORS. CORS must be processed before Spring Security, because the pre-flight request does not contain any cookies (that is, the `JSESSIONID`). If the request does not contain any cookies and Spring Security is first, the request determines that the user is not authenticated (since there are no cookies in the request) and rejects it.
>
> The easiest way to ensure that CORS is handled first is to use the `CorsFilter`. Users can integrate the `CorsFilter` with Spring Security by providing a `CorsConfigurationSource` that uses the following:
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class WebSecurityConfig {
>
>   @Bean
>   public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>       http
>           // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
>           .cors(withDefaults())
>           ...
>       return http.build();
>   }
>
>   @Bean
>   CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
>       CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
>       configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
>       configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
>       UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
>       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
>       return source;
>   }
> }
> ```

With Spring Security 5/6 you don't need to configure CORS twice (Spring Security and Spring MVC):

> If you use Spring MVC’s CORS support, you can omit specifying the `CorsConfigurationSource` and Spring Security uses the CORS configuration provided to Spring MVC:

Comment: Still getting CORS-Error when trying this solution:

`[...] has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: This throws a type mismatch error: > Type mismatch: cannot convert from UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource to CorsConfigurationSource

Comment: @dur spring-boot-starter-parent=3.1.2, spring-boot-starter-security=3.1.2, so Spring Security 6.1.2 and using spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server=1.1.1. But `withDefaults()` is undefined :/

Comment: Okay, so I needed to import the static method: `import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;`

Answer (score 18):

Since Spring Security 4.1, this is the proper way to make Spring Security support CORS (also needed in Spring Boot 1.4/1.5):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    }
}
```

and:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
        // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
        // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Do *not* do any of below, which are the wrong way to attempt solving the problem:

- `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll();`
- `web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);`

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to use http.csrf().disable() because iOS and Android Apps would be blocked when not enabled. Now both is working WEB and Mobile.

Comment: Thank you! this solved my issue! In particular, it was adding configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type")); that I was missing.

Comment: For Spring 5+ replace `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` with `implements WebMvcConfigurer`. (see https://www.baeldung.com/web-mvc-configurer-adapter-deprecated for an explanation). Also, I used `Arrays.asList` instead of `ImmutableList`.

Comment: Why is the first configuration necessary when we have the identical second one?

Answer (score 1):

Since none of this posted examples helped me, I've taken things in my own knowledge.

In this method:

```java
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration cors = new CorsConfiguration();
    cors.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "HEAD", "DELETE"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

`CorsConfiguration` by default have allowed method: `POST`, `HEAD`, `GET`, so `PUT`, `DELETE` **will not work**. What I did is I created a new instance of `CorsConfiguration` and set allowed methods:

```java
cors.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "HEAD", "DELETE"));
```

so now my method looks like:

```java
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration cors = new CorsConfiguration();
    cors.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "HEAD", "DELETE"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", cors.applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

Of course, all other configuration is made by Spring documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below configuration in the main application. It worked me in **spring boot application 2.3.1**

```
package com.example.restservicecors;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestServiceCorsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServiceCorsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*").allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

**Reference source**: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Spring Security 6, as it was ignoring my CORS Configuration.
If you want to be truly sure the SecurityConfig picks up your custom CorsConfiguration, you may also enforce it with:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
       .authorizeRequests()
           ...
       .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(yourCustomCorsConfigurationSource))
           ...;
}
```

Comment: I tried this also but still giving me same error

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular with Spring Boot. This is the config that worked for me:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll() // Angular httpClient uses OPTIONS first in all requests
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .headers()
            .frameOptions().disable(); // For swagger
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
            new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have Resource Server with OAuth security enabled and any of above solutions didn't work. After some debugging and googling figured why.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Basically in this example `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` is key!

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/938

Various pom dependencies add different kinds of filters and therefore we could have issues based on order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class CorsFilterConfig {

    public static final List<String> allowedOrigins = Arrays.asList("*");

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> initCorsFilter() {
        // @formatter:off
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add the `@CrossOrigin` annotation to allow all of them if you use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. And in the security configurations the `http.cors().and()`. This worked for me.

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
        customAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
        http
            .csrf().disable();
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // We can ant match out paths to the corresponding roles --> we allow certain roles to access certain API's
        http
            .cors()
                .and(); 
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll(); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using a CloudFront distribution for the UI code deployed on S3. From S3, the UI code requests go to the API server, and I encountered the same error in the browser console. It was misleading, indicating CORS issues, but the root cause was CloudFront's inability to connect to the origin server. Therefore, it's essential to check the health and reachability of the origin server to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for: spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.6.RELEASE

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*").allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

Change "*" to something meaningful in prod

Comment: This won't work if you use Spring Security.