# Not able to invoke cross domain request in Jquery-Ajax

Tags: ajax, rest, spring-security, cross-domain, wildfly

I  know this is most searched issue in google, still it didn't worked for me. I am trying to call cross domain request from jquery ajax to services running in wildfly with spring authentication.

Service invocation has happened successfully for anonymous authentication, but when i added authorization it is giving below error.

Failed to load , Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) 
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

below is my $.ajax code.

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: actionURL,
            crossDomain: true,
              xhrFields: {
                  withCredentials: true
                },
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:pwd')
                },  
            //dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data) {
            console.log('Status: ok'+JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (data) { console.log("errosdsrddd!!" + JSON.stringify(data)); }
        });
```

and I have enabled cors in wildfly server with following config

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <https-listener name="default-https" tcp-keep-alive="true" read-timeout="600000" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" verify-client="REQUESTED"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"/>
                <filter-ref name="Access-Control-Max-Age"/>
                <single-sign-on/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <session-cookie http-only="true" secure="true"/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header-value="*"/>
            <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header-value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT"/>
            <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header-value="accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with"/>
            <response-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header-value="true"/>
            <response-header name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-name="Access-Control-Max-Age" header-value="1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

tried all the ways in front end and back end still no luck.

It would be appreciable for any suggestions and solutions.

please refer below for header info.

```
General
   Request URL:<url>
   Request Method:OPTIONS
   Status Code:401 Unauthorized
   Remote Address:192.168.175.73:8445
   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
   view source
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
   Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type, x-
   requested-with
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
   Access-Control-Max-Age:1
   Connection:keep-alive
   Content-Length:114
   Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
   Date:Tue, 09 Jan 2018 06:29:25 GMT
   Server:WildFly/10
   Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=x1noix9B_CC_bg3b-
           OhykAXTs7wwWpk3CEcygeKB.syncgdc1769; path=/syntbotsservices; 
   secure; HttpOnly
   WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Spring Security Application"
   X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
Request Headers
   view source
   Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
   Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,cache-control,postman-token
   Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
   Connection:keep-alive
   Host:192.168.175.73:8445
   Origin:http://localhost:8081
   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
              Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Preflight calls must not contain username and password (as you can see in your edit). Could it be, that you didn't allow anonymous access for all HTTP `OPTION` calls in your Spring Security configuration, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021652/5277820.

Comment: That is not the point. The preflight never contains any credentials. So you have to allow anonymous access for preflight. See the link in my last comment.

Comment: Thanks sir, It worked.