# Angular 6 + Spring framework 5 + Spring security

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have built a project in spring 5. Then I started to configure the login in angular(CORS) but it just gives me the error 401 in the options preflight.
I am stuck with this one, if you have something to help let me know.
Backend project: https://github.com/maiconpintoabreu/Spring5SecurityMongodbTest
Thanks

## Fixed with @Order and Cors configuration

```
@Order(4)
```

public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .httpBasic().and().cors().and();           
}
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
  UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
  source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
  return source;
}
```

}

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

Comment: you have add @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200") in your calling controller at class level or perticular method level

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016126/cors-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested

Comment: Hi I add all the Cors configurations and it didn't work, the @CrossOrigin in the controller (but the problem is when I call /oauth/token, and I try to permit all for Options request as well.

Comment: Sorry guys I didn't realize the Order on configuration was so important, it fixed my problem, Thanks.