# spring security and spring boot 2 with cors Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I am getting  below error  . can somebody help me how to configure cors in spring boot with spring security.
is there any thing I have to do fro UI side in angularjs.

> Failed to load http://localhost:8080/SpringGeolocation/login: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. (index):70 {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ,
>   getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
>   all.min.js:9566 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin
>   response http://localhost:8080/SpringGeolocation/login with MIME type
>   application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

### spring boot 2 along with spring security

package com.geo.config;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import com.geo.security.LogoutSuccessHandler;
import com.geo.security.RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint;


@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    public static final String REMEMBER_ME_KEY = "rememberme_key";

    public SecurityConfiguration() {
        super();
        logger.info("loading SecurityConfig ................................................ ");
    }

    @Autowired
    private RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler restAccessDeniedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler restAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler restAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Autowired
    LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyAuthority("admin", "user")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().antMatchers("/role/**").hasAnyAuthority("admin")

                .and().exceptionHandling()
                 .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .accessDeniedHandler(restAccessDeniedHandler).and().formLogin().loginPage("/login") // by putting this
                                                                                                    // or by applying
                                                                                                    // authentication
                // entrypoint default login page would not appear
                // .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .successHandler(restAuthenticationSuccessHandler).failureHandler(restAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").permitAll().and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll()
                .and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices).rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .rememberMeCookieName("remember-me").key(REMEMBER_ME_KEY);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/index.html", "/login.html", "/partials/**", "/template/**", "/",
                "/error/**");
    }



}
```

### properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/googlemap
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug


logging.level.root=info
#server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false

management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://localhost:8080
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.geo")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
    }

}
```

Comment: In addCors also allow expose headers with “Access-control-allow-header” please check spell and actual name in your error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS issue - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016126/cors-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested)

Answer (score 3):

Adding allow headers and expose headers should work.

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                .allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin")
            .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin");

    }
```