# Integration of Spring Boot application with Angular application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to integrate Spring Boot application with Angular application. Both applications are running on a different server. When I will try to hit REST API from the Angular application API hit successfully but I get an error response on UI.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9092/jobs/postal/launch' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I implemented the CORS negotiation on the backend side. So I just want that I am able to hit the backend from UI without any security.

I also read the below article to get an understanding of CORS and CSRF.

https://markitzeroday.com/x-requested-with/cors/2017/06/29/csrf-mitigation-for-ajax-requests.html

```java
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings( CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping(corsMapping)
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
                .allowedMethods(allowedMethods).allowedHeaders("X-Requested-With");
        }
    };
}
```

I just want to know how can I get successfully integrate Spring Boot application with Angular application.

If there is any doc or link that can help me please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS issue - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016126/cors-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS manages the access to the requests originating from the servers other than where backend application is deployed. By-default it is set to only the backend hosting server due to security reasons which means only requests originating from backend hosting server are allowed.

In your case since both backend and UI are running on separate servers you need to add some code changes in backend to allow the UI to access the backend.

You can have a class `ResourceApplication.java` as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@CrossOrigin(origins="*", maxAge=3600)
public Message home() {
  return new Message("Hello World");
}
```

The above is taken from [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) tutorial which is provided by spring.io and is an excellent guide if you are integrating spring-boot with angular. If you scroll down you will find the CORS section.

Comment: The above code is also doing the same. I am able to hit the back end but I am not able to read the response.

Comment: Actually, it is a CORS error because the browser is not able to read the response. But if I will add X-Requested-With header in UI. I will get pre-flight request error due to CSRF. I just want to hit successfully without getting any error. I already read the spring security doc. I also read the doc that I shared having an explanation of CORS and CSRF

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9092/jobs/postal/launch' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Comment: @YugSingh you are right but the browser is not able to read the response.

Comment: It's working fine guys. Normal cors mapping annotation is working fine. In my case, it is some other issue.