# Angular application is not rendering the data from Spring Boot API deployed in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have one wired error,

I have Angular application running in my local machine.
I have Spring Boot Application pod running in Google Kubernetes Engine.

Every End point works fine other than one end point.

Error logs:

```
Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.
add-sales:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://34.72.237.38:8080/vehicles/2' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
add-sales.component.ts:63 Error in getting the single vehicle :  
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://34.72.237.38:8080/vehicles/2", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://34.72.237.38:8080/vehicles/2: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://34.72.237.38:8080/vehicles/2"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

When I hit the above URL in the browser, the data is rendering in the JSON format. I don't know why it is not rending in the Component.ts file when I call this service from service class.

Service Class

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VehicleDetailsService {

  vehicleDetails : VehicleDetails;

  
  
  url="http://34.72.237.38:8080";
  // url = "http://localhost:8080";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



  getVehicleDetails(id : number){
    return this.http.get<VehicleDetails>(this.url+`/vehicle/${id}/vehicleDetail`);
  }
}
```

Component Class:

```
getSingleVehicle(){
    return this.vehicle_service.getSingleVehicles(this.vehicleID)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.vehicle = res;
        console.log("Response for single vehicle : ",this.vehicle);
      },
      err=>{
        console.log("Error in getting the single vehicle : ",err);
      })
    }
```

Spring Boot Controller Class

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class VehicleController {
    
    @Autowired
    public VehicleService vehService;
    
    @GetMapping("/vehicles/{id}")
    public Optional<Vehicle> getVehicleById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return vehService.getSingleVehicle(id);
    }

}
```

It's my spring security configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/console/**").permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

Here I am allowing all Urls, but I am still not able to rend the data in angular.

Comment: You'll need to fix the CORS configuration on the Spring side of things to get it working properly. See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016126/cors-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested).

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows no cross origin requests are allowed from your local development machine (`localhost:4200`) to the deployed application.
Since you have a `@CrossOrigin` annotation present on the controller as shown in your question there must be a different kind of problem.
Hypothesis: You did not build and deploy a new version of the app after adding the `@CrossOrigin`. Another option could be a reverse proxy that filters CORS headers.