# Spring not not receiving Authentication header from Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I am creating a Rest microservice with SpringBoot and Swagger (using `springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core` v1.6.5). To enable and configurate Swagger I created this class:

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeIn;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "User Management API", version = "1.0", description = "Documentation User Management API v1.0"))
@SecurityScheme(name = OpenApi30Config.SECURITY_SCHEME_NAME, scheme = "Bearer", type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP, in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER )
public class OpenApi30Config {

    public static final String SECURITY_SCHEME_NAME = "Authorization";

}
```

One of the endpoints looks like this:

```java
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/roles", name = "Role Controller")
@Tag(name = "Roles", description = "Controller to get the information of the HORUS role users.")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@SecurityRequirement(name = OpenApi30Config.SECURITY_SCHEME_NAME)
public class RoleController {

    @Operation(summary = "Returns all Role Users")
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "All registered Roles Found", content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json", array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = RRole.class)))}),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "No Users Found", content = {@Content()})
    })
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<RRole>> findAllRoles() {
...
    }
}
```

I Configurated my swagger to user JWT authentication which will be intercepted by a filter:

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AuthenticatedFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

   @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException {
        log.debug("FILTER: {}", request.getRequestURI());

        // LOG ALL HEADERS
        Collections
                .list(request.getHeaderNames())
                .forEach(headerNAme -> log.debug("FILTER {} : {}", headerNAme, request.getHeader(headerNAme)));
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        // I use this requestTokenHeader for authentication
        
    }
    
}
```

In image below you can see the swagger page. There, I already filled the authorization. When I sent my request, the authorization is sent in the header (`'Authorization: Bearer eyJhb...`). However, for some reason it is not reaching the filter. In the line `LOG ALL HEADERS`, it is showing all headers except by Authorization.
[image]

But, if I repeat the request using cUrl, the Authorization is received by filter (Image below).
[image]

This I believe that I did some mistake when I configured `@OpenAPIDefinition` or `@SecurityScheme`, but I was not able to find exactly what.

Comment: Are there any errors on the "Console" tab in the dev tools? According to the "Transferred" column on your 1st screenshot, there's a NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI error that prevents the GET request from actually reaching the server. Does your API server [support CORS](https://enable-cors.org/server.html)?

Comment: Indeed, there is a error message in console: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.207:50000/api/roles. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 400.` I will research how to configure Spring OpenAPI to deal with this problem.

Comment: OK: I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016126/cors-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested or more exactly, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65264237/1659543