# CORS Error: Spring Boot Multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in my code:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class BoardSecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final X509BoardDetailsService x509BoardDetailsService;

    public BoardSecurityConf(X509BoardDetailsService x509BoardDetailsService) {
        this.x509BoardDetailsService = x509BoardDetailsService;
    }




    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/board/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/board/all")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .x509()
                .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                .userDetailsService(x509BoardDetailsService);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class UserSecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    private final JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    public UserSecurityConf(JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter, JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService) {
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
        this.jwtUserDetailsService = jwtUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/user/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/authenticate")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


    @Bean
    JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }
}
```

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(3)
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

When I access my site from an ajax request I get:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/user/authenticate' from origin 'http://localhost:8082' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I think I have some missconfiguration in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters. Already checked Spring documentation but coult not find anything about cors and mutltiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configurations

@EDIT:

Now I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*" since that cannot be set on the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" response header. To allow credentials to a set of origins, list them explicitly or consider using "allowedOriginPatterns" instead.
    at org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration.validateAllowCredentials(CorsConfiguration.java:473) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:532) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1261) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS issue - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016126/cors-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested)

Comment: You didn't configure CORS for `http://localhost:8080/user/authenticate`, you only configured it for other URLs than `/board/**` and `/user/**`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Apparently the libary `SockJS` that I am using as STOMP Client sets the `withCredentials` flag to true [(see Issue)](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/257) in their XHR. When this flag is set you are not allowed to use a wildcard as AllowedOrigin on Cors.

Therefore I changed:

```java
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

to this:

```java
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8082", "https://localhost:8082"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

I also added `.cors(withDefaults())` to each WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which automatically uses my bean from `corsConfigurationSource()` [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title)