# CORS configuration with Spring Security and Vue.js

Tags: java, spring, vue.js, rest, spring-security

I created a Vue-Spring login API, which looks correct.

AuthForm.vue

```js
methods: {
  try_auth() {
    if (this.check()) {
      axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login', {
        params: {
          login: this.usr.login,
          password: this.usr.password
        }
      });
    }
  },
}
```

LoginController.java:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:8081")
public class LoginContoller {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path="/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleLoginRequest(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String password) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Authentication successful: " + login + " " + password);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT","OPTIONS","PATCH", "DELETE"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                )
                .formLogin((formLogin) ->
                        formLogin
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
                                .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        UserDetails user =
                User.builder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to execute the `try_auth()` method, I get [image] in the console. What did I implement wrong? The Vue project is deployed on port 8081 and Tomcat is running on port 8080.
My question is different from [CORS issue - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016126/cors-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested) , because this solution is not suitable for me, I still got 403 error and don't know how to fix it. My LoginController may be used incorrectly.
So, here's my code after fixes:
LoginController didn't change. Axios on frontend didn't change as well. SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                )
                .formLogin((formLogin) ->
                        formLogin
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
                                .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        UserDetails user =
                User.builder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:8081"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Still got

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/api/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.
```

Comment: BTW: Your `LoginContoller` makes no sense. You have to call the `/login` endpoint which you are configured.

Comment: @muzzletov It doesn't matter, the form login endpoint is exposed by Spring Security and is at `/login`. The controller makes no sense at all, because he must be loggend in to call this endpoint `/api/login`. This will return a 302 redirect to `/login`.

Comment: @dur , I implemented the variant on your link but still got 403

Comment: @MC_Vovi Are you still use `POST` on `http://localhost:8080/api/login`? This endpoint is restricted for authenticated users: `.requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")`. You have to send your credentials to `/login`. But this will also not work, because you doesn't send CSRF token.

Comment: @MC_Vovi There is also another problem. The form login parameters are `username` and `password`, not `login`.

Comment: @dur yes, sorry, i just saw myself that hes using the formlogin directive

Answer (score 0):

**why the error :**

- your `http.cors`  in `SecurityConfig.java` does not allow request form port 8081. this is spring default security phenomena

**how we can solve this :**

- you have to allow your port 8081 inside java application. we can do this as follows
- you need to update  `registry.addMapping` and allowedMethods

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8081")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

- please update your security config as follows

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                )
                .formLogin((formLogin) ->
                        formLogin
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
                                .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
}
```

Comment: got Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/login;jsessionid=4897CB13AF8C7B7965EAA022B04511AA. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 302. and Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch to '/api/login' (previous null). Performing CorsConfiguration lookup. This is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE. on backend

Comment: please try update  corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:8081")); in your SecurityConfig.java

Comment: now got 403 error

Comment: nothing changed((. Idk, maybe I should set necessary headers manually?

Comment: This answer is faulty, how to setup CORS in spring security is very clearly defined in the spring security CORS chapter in the documentation. The configuration posted here is for configuring a spring MVC application.