# Spring CORS error: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security, spring-security, cors

I am using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.5` with `spring-security` deployed as a backend spring boot app in openshift as a container. Also have an angular 11.0.1 front-end app hosted on another container. During testing from front-end app to backend, I am getting CORS error. Below is the error message in the browser console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.apps.ocpa.company.com/app/user/config' from origin 'https://frontend.apps.ocpa.company.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I have the cors configuration enabled in MvcConfig class shown below

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${cors.allowed-origins:*}")
    String allowedOrigins;


    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }

}
```

still I am getting this error

Comment: Duplicate [How to configure CORS in a Spring Boot + Spring Security application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968963/how-to-configure-cors-in-a-spring-boot-spring-security-application)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS issue - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016126/cors-issue-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested)

Comment: Hello Dur, both `httpSecurity.cors()` in `configure` method and `configuration.setAllowCredentials(true)` in `corsConfigurationSource() ` in  `WebSecurityConfig ` wasn't found together in any example, I have to spent a long time with several trials and searches to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by adding the following code snippet in 'public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter'. Several of the stackoverflow posts was referred but I couldn't find anyone, that specifically advices on `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'` header missing in the http response from server. Keep the configuration same in `MvcConfig` and `WebSecurityConfig` is very important

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()......
    }



@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        
       configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(allowedOrigins));
       configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
       configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

`configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);` was required to set the correct response headers, in addition to below configuration in MvcConfig

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${cors.allowed-origins:*}")
    String allowedOrigins;


    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/**")
                //.allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }

}
```

and add your backend hostname to the property `cors.allowed-origins` in `application.properties` as below

```
cors.allowed-origins=https://app-name.domain.com
```